# Where is this place "city on the rock"?

Tags: where-on-earth

Where is this place "city on the rock"?

[image]

Comment: @KateGregory, it is not working in my locolized version of Windows 10

Comment: what happens when you click on the question at the top right that has a camera icon next to it?

Comment: right click -> "Search Google for image" -> get your answer at the top of the page

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The photo was taken in [Ronda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronda), Andalucía, Spain.

Ronda is a very touristic town, in particular around the bridge, which is its main tourist attraction.  You can get there by train from Antequera or Algeciras, or by bus from Sevilla, Malaga, or smaller towns closer-by.

The bridge is called Puente Nuevo.  Here is the same bridge from another angle:

[image]
[*Source: Wikimedia Commons*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ronda_09_Puente_Nuevo_(4579241071).jpg)

For a large gallery of photos, see [Wikimedia Commons on Puento Nuevo de Ronda](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Puente_Nuevo_de_Ronda).

P.S. Be careful if you want to [rent a car in Ronda](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/86259/2509)!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 9):

You can simply click on like what you see, Those windows images are called spotlight images,

[image]

Comment: I know I like that, need to know the name of the place!

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko in your question you mention where , and i am saying if you click on like what you see it will tell you in ronda, spain as the image shows

Comment: Sorry, did n't check your image carefully. Check it in my version of Windows 10, it is not working. Just "Like/Dislike"((

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko maybe it needs update ? localy it is visible for me

Comment: @Moudiz It tends not to show every time. Maybe there is more than one version of the picture in the collection and some of them lack the location info.